# Dispatch swipe gesture to superview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I need to forward swipe event from uiwebview to it's superview (uiscrollview) when swipe direction is from left to right. So, I'm trying to do smth like this

```
self.swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeGestureRecognizer];
```

and handler

```
-(void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) swipeRecognizer {

if(swipeRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {

   //change to dispatching swipe to scrollview
    CGPoint contentOffset = [self.scrollView contentOffset];
    contentOffset.x -= 1024;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
}}
```

Instead changing scrollview offset I wan't to forward swipe to it. How can I do this ?

Comment: if possible can you explain what exactly you want to achieve from this..!

Comment: scrollview should scroll when left swipe on webview  happens